# AEM Quickstart License Key

Tags: aem

I've been given an AEM quickstart jar file and license.properties from a client and I'm trying to set up a local dev environment as described here: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-learn/foundation/development/set-up-a-local-aem-development-environment.html?lang=en#install-apache-maven

But on step 6; opening the jar file. This starts a local server and I get this screen:

[image]

What **"license key"** is this expecting? And where do I find that. Nothing in the `license.properties` supplied seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: It's a separate license key that has to be copied and pasted into the edit control. It's issued by Adobe when the product is purchased, and is for the specific customer that made the purchase (which is why it also asks for the customer name). Your customer should confirm that allowing you to use it is permissible under their license agreement.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks Ken. I have separately received an invite from adobe and have access to the clients account on https://experience.adobe.com/. Would I find that license key in there somewhere, or is this something my client has to provide?

Comment: It would be something your client has to provide. It's issued to them when they've paid for the product, and is client specific, and has to be paired with the exact company name to which it was issued. I'm not sure about AEM, but other Adobe products validate them when they're entered and block access if they don't match properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming fair use of the license, just put the `license.properties` next to the JAR, AEM will recognize the license during the start up.

Answer (score 1):

I was faced this issue when I upgraded my MAC. The below solution worked for me.
Open your **license.properties** file in text editor and copy paste the **license.customer.name** and **license.downloadID** values in to the dialog box and submit.

After submitting the values the login screen pops up.

Answer (score 0):

As AEM is a licensed product, YOu would require a license to run the local jar file. You should get the jar file from your:

- Company Admin
- Adobe partner manager
- Send an email to spphelp@adobe.com to obtain one on behalf of your company.

How to use it?
Option 1:
YOu can place the license.properties file next to the aem-quickstart.jar file and when you run the jar file automatically it should take it.

Option 2:
In the case of MAC sometimes the license.properties file does not recognize even if you placed it next to the AEM JAR file.
In that case
copy the license file to a different folder.
delete the license file from the AEM JAR folder
copy below properties from the license file

- customer.name >> Customer Name &
- downloadId >> license Key

Refer to https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/aem-license-and-installation/td-p/397135 for Adobe communities answer.